# OpenCV (3.3.0) returns fail on VideoCapture with Video but works with Webcam [OS X]

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, capture

Thanks for reading already, I've been trying to get this to work for a day and I didn't get closer to the solution.

I'm trying to get this [object tracker](https://github.com/bikz05/object-tracker) to work. When I use a video from my webcam (with: `python object-tracker-single.py -d 0`, everything works as expected.

But as soon as I'm trying to use a video file (i've tried different formats: `.mp4`, `.mkv` & `.avi`. I also tried to use the file given in the repository, that didn't work as well. To see if there is a `File not found`-Error, I passed an invalid path to the function and an error got printed, that has not been printed when I used the other videos. So the file(s) i'm using is(/are) valid and not corrupted.

I installed `dlib` through `homebrew` following [this article](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-dlib-on-macos/) and compiled `OpenCV` from the official source. This is the [CMakeCache.txt](https://pastebin.com/6tAEC3iC) that `CMake` spit out. After the first time I compiled it, I added [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) to the mix, thinking that it could help (I also think that I actually needed it), but that didn't fix the problem.

This is the code I'm having problems with:

```
# Create the VideoCapture object
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(source)

# If Camera Device is not opened, exit the program
if not cam.isOpened():
    print "Video device or file couldn't be opened"
    exit()

print "Press key `p` to pause the video to start tracking"
while True:
    # Retrieve an image and Display it.
    retval, img = cam.read() #<-- this returns false when trying to read a video 
    if not retval:
        print "Cannot capture frame device"
        exit()
```

At the marked line, `retval` equals `False` and `image` equals `None`. 
It would already help me if I could somehow debug this behavior, but I didn't find any way of doing so.

I found that many Windows Users had problems with missing `ffmpeg` support, but that is not the case for me, since I used `ffmpeg` in previous (not OpenCV-related) projects and `CMakeCache.txt` reports that `ffmpeg` has been found and the compilation succeeded.

I also tried using a fully qualified file-name for the video file, which either resulted in `Video device or file couldn't be opened` or the given problem.

If you have any idea how this problem can be completely resolved, have an Idea on how to solve it or can provide me with a way of properly debugging this behavior, I'd be super glad to here it!

Thanks already!

-

System: MacBook Pro (macOS Sierra `10.12.6`)

OpenCV Version: `3.3.0`

Dlib Version (not necessary imo, but hey): `19.4.0`

**Edit 2**
Output of `cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-master/modules ../ >> result.txt`: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/KbHPQm3L)

Comment: Did you test the code with hardcoded path e.g `cam = cv2.VideoCapture("/home/video.mp4")`?

Comment: @Zindarod same behaviour, no difference

Comment: Go to your OpenCV build folder and run `cmake .. >> result.txt`, post the file here.

Comment: @Zindarod Edit 2 ^^

Comment: Well I couldn't find any problem with your `cmake` output. Wait and see if someone else spots something. In the meantime, will you install `libv4l-dev`, run `cmake` and build OpenCV again. See if this solves the issue.

Comment: @Zindarod I'm on OS X, [this](http://rosindex.github.io/d/libv4l-dev/)  states that it doesn't exist for macOS

Comment: Ok then lets hope someone else spots the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround by now using the [scikit-video](http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/io.html) and the linked `skvideo.io.FFmpegReader()` function. Through that I was able to read the all the videos I tested inbefore frame-by-frame.

This is the code that replaces the code in my original question:

```
reader = skvideo.io.FFmpegReader("/Users/timomueller/Desktop/test_video_carcounting.mp4", inputdict=inputparameters, outputdict=outputparameters);

print "Press key `p` to pause the video to start tracking"
for img in reader.nextFrame():
    #img contains the frame - the for loop runs until there is 
    #no frame available anymore
```

If you're facing the same problem as I do, I think that `scikit-video` is a good workaround and I'll focus on working on my actual problem instead of fixing `OpenCV` from now on.

Installation through `pip` is quiet easy. Simply `sudo pip install sk-video` and wait until the command finishes. Then you can `import skvideo.io` and everything should work fine!

The only problem I was having with this workaround is that `img` seems tinted as if it lost it's colors or as if there were incorrect settings regarding color space, pixel format, etc. For me this is not crucial, so I will simply ignore that and probably work on it later on. (If I find a fix, I'll update this answer). For everyone that needs correct colors, take a look at the documentation regarding `inputdict` and `outputdict` (`skvideo.io.FFmpegReader(file, inputdict, outputdict)`). As well as `FFmpeg`'s [video filters](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Video-Filters). It should be possible to fix the tinted colors with that or with proper pixel format settings in the `outputdict`.

But maybe the tinting problem doesn't affect you, in that case: I hope this helped.

Be sure to add your answer if you find an actual solution to the problem though!

Comment: Appreciate this is an old post but the tinting is likely due to OpenCV using BGR and skvideo using RGB. You'd need to use the OpenCV `cvtColor()` function.

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer to it though @mstreffo - I don't even remember what exactly I was working on when posting this, but your answer will probably help anyone that might encounter this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with OpenCV 3.3.0. on Ubuntu 14.04.

The reason cv2.VideoCapture failed, seems to be because of a wrong installation of OpenCV.

The official way of installation should be followed: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html

I had installed using pip, clearly not working.

I ended up just pulling a docker image:
https://hub.docker.com/r/victorhcm/opencv/

That worked perfectly.